# How to plot confidence intervals for stattools ccf function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, statsmodels

I am computing the cross-correlation function using [ccf](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.ccf.htmlv) from statsmodels. It works fine except I can't see how to also plot the confidence intervals.  I notice that [acf](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf.html) seems to have much more functionality.  Here is a toy example just to have something to see:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as stattools

def create(n):
    x = np.zeros(n)
    for i in range(1, n):
        if np.random.rand() < 0.9:
            if np.random.rand() < 0.5:
                x[i] = x[i-1] + 1
        else:
            x[i] = np.random.randint(0,100)
    return x
x = create(4000)
y = create(4000)
plt.plot(stattools.ccf(x, y)[:100])
```

This gives:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the confidence interval is not provided by the statsmodels cross-correlation function ([ccf](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.ccf.html)). In R the ccf() would also print the confidence interval.

Here, we need to calculate the confidence interval by ourself and plot it out afterwards. The confidence interval is here computed as `2 / np.sqrt(lags)`. For basic info on confidence intervals for cross-correlation refer to:

- Stats StackExchange answer by Rob Hyndman: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3128/43304

> ```
> import numpy as np
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as stattools
>
> def create(n):
>     x = np.zeros(n)
>     for i in range(1, n):
>         if np.random.rand() < 0.9:
>             if np.random.rand() < 0.5:
>                 x[i] = x[i-1] + 1
>         else:
>             x[i] = np.random.randint(0,100)
>     return x
> x = create(4000)
> y = create(4000)
>
> lags= 4000
> sl = 2 / np.sqrt(lags)
>
> plt.plot(x, list(np.ones(lags) * sl), color='r')
> plt.plot(x, list(np.ones(lags) * -sl), color='r')
>
> plt.plot(stattools.ccf(x, y)[:100])
> ```

This leads to the following plot with the additional red lines:
[image: CI Plot]